# SVG vs PNG if icons appear at multiple places

Tags: html, performance, svg, optimization

I am optimizing a site. As suggested in [this CSS-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/), I am planning to `<use>` SVG icons. I am a bit skeptical due to my use case.

Most of the icons are placed once(or twice) in a page for which SVG `<use>` is fine.

**But there are two icons** which has to be placed at **multiple places**(approx. 20-50 times each) in a single page. For this particular page, is it better to use PNG because PNG method will benefit *browser caching*?

Will SVG  method bloat the HTML document with the same icons being repeated, say 50 times?

Please answer even if this sounds like a premature optimization. I am refactoring the existing site's code. I have already checked [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303801/looking-for-a-research-png-sprite-vs-svg-sprite-vs-icon-fonts).

Asking again because:

1. My particular use case.
2. Hoping things have changed in 2022.

Comment: Maybe you can save an SVG in a file and use it the same way as PNG.

Comment: Just use CSS (https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) and delay concerns of optimizations? (because there will be minimal cost to change it later; in the case of an “icon” it’s likely *decoration* and not document content)

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks. I will use SVG sprite and use it as external resource which will be cached by browsers. I hope this method won't need polyfill in 2022.

Comment: Or let all the icon SVG be created _once_ by a modern native Web Component ``<svg-icon>`` _client-side_: https://iconmeister.github.io